# How to convert list of dictionaries to new dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

To convert list of dictionary already present in the dataset to a dataframe. The dataset looks something like this.
the records type are in string type, so i have challenges to convert to list first and i was confused how to convert it. the data was in a column csv files

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H17D.png)
i tried to use json_normalize() but it didn't work
i wanted to create new dataframe from that column
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) by `occupations` column, then convert strings to dictionaries by `literal_eval` and last create new columns in [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) with append to another columns:

```
import ast

out = df.explode('occupations').reset_index(drop=True)

out = out.join(pd.json_normalize(out.pop('occupations').apply(ast.literal_eval)))
```